# What's the probability of drawing four different suits when picking five cards?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Considering an infinite and perfectly random deck of cards (or just repositioning the cards and shuffling a normal deck after every drawn card), how do I calculate the probability that exactly x suits will be pulled out with y tries? For example if we draw five cards from the deck, what's the probability of all four suits being present?

I bruteforced this scenario for 5 cards by generating every possible combination and considering it equally likely (since I'm repositioning the cards after every draw), and found the following values: 4/1024 for exactly one suit, 180/1024 for two, 600/1024 for three and 240/1024 for four suits.

The way I bruteforced it was: I generated all possible combinations with five loops iterating from 0 to 4, appending every iteration to a list, then running the following function to check if a combination has exactly n different suits for every element in the list:

```py
def valid(l, n):
    arr = [l[0]]
    for i in range(0, len(l)):
        aux = 0
        for j in range(0, len(arr)):
            if arr[j] == l[i]:
                aux = 1
        if aux == 0:
            arr.append(l[i])
    return len(arr) == n
```

It's a trivial matter for one suit, however when considering four of them I could not reach the expected value: 1/4^4 for a specific combination (considering the fifth card might be anything), times the number of ways to arrange those 4 cards in 5 slots (120) = 120/256, roughly two times my bruteforced result.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you write code for your brute force attempt? If so share it

Comment: I mostly worked on the interpreter, the only code I saved is now in the post